# CG: repeating a texture using fmod causes aliasing

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, antialiasing, cg

I'm writing `Cg` shaders using `Unity3D`.

I'm trying to use [fmod](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/fmod.html) function to repeat a texture along an axis (basically the same effect I can achieve by setting the texture scale in `Material` with `TextureWrapMode.Repeat` ).

This is the `fragment shader` code that can reproduce the error:

```
half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
{

  float u_sample_coord = fmod(i.uv.x ,period) /period;
  half4 col =tex2D(myTexture,float2(u_sample_coord, i.uv.y));  
  return col;
}
```

Basically it seems to work but it produces some sort of aliasing (a strip pattern) in correspondance with 0's of fmod function.
Here's some screenshot:

[image]

The image above shows how texture repeats correctly. 
Here's a zoom on the strip aliasing pattern emerged:

[image]

I tried to debug it but I can't figure out what's going on exactly. 
Anyone could tell me what's the problem and eventually how to solve it?

---

EDIT:
I found out that disabling mipmap generation solve this problem. Btw I'd like to use mipmap to avoid minification aliasing problem while the distance increase. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly set the u and v derivatives in the tex2D() function. But: why are you using fmod? If the sampler's repeat mode is set to wrap, then you can let the UV coordinates roam far beyond the 0-1 range. It will wrap by itself.

Comment: Yes, I solved passing the derivatives explicitely. Of course my shader does a little bit more than repeating a texture :). I just simplified the code to show the problem. I'm procedurally texturing building facades. I need to calculate texture coordinates procedurally.